# assign different color to line segments

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a curve which construct by 3 segments, I would like to assign different color to it.

But current code, the last command `[green]` wins.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.15]
  \definecolor{red}{HTML}{F00000}
  \definecolor{blue}{HTML}{0000F0}
  \definecolor{green}{HTML}{008000}

  \coordinate (P1) at (6,6);
  \coordinate (P2) at (22,30);
  \coordinate (P3) at (42,30);
  \coordinate (P4) at (70,24);

  \coordinate (C1) at (11.16,16);
  \coordinate (C2) at (16.31,26);
  \coordinate (C3) at (27.69,34);
  \coordinate (C4) at (33.91,32);
  \coordinate (C5) at (50.09,28);
  \coordinate (C6) at (60.04,26);

   \draw[line width=2]
        (P1) [red] .. controls (C1) and (C2) ..
        (P2) [blue] .. controls (C3) and (C4) ..
        (P3) [green] .. controls (C5) and (C6) ..
        (P4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

### Update

I use the answer below and wish to fix the connection smooth issue.
So update a new example which more obviously saw the smooth issue if use three draw command.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \definecolor{red}{HTML}{F00000}
  \definecolor{blue}{HTML}{0000F0}
  \definecolor{green}{HTML}{008000}

  \coordinate (P1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (P2) at (2,2);
  \coordinate (P3) at (3,1);
  \coordinate (P4) at (5,3);

   \draw[line width=10, red] (P1) -- (P2);
   \draw[line width=10, blue] (P2) -- (P3);
   \draw[line width=10, green] (P3) -- (P4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could split your curve: `\draw[red] (P1) .. controls (C1) and (C2) .. (P2) ;     
\draw[blue] (P2) .. controls (C3) and (C4) .. (P3);    
\draw[green] (P3) .. controls (C5) and (C6) .. (P4);`

Answer (score 1):

Just draw the exact same thing several times in different colors - gives a perfectly smooth curve.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (1,3);
\draw[red] plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (1,2) (3,1) (4,3)};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (1,0) rectangle (3,3);
\draw[green] plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (1,2) (3,1) (4,3)};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (3,0) rectangle (4,3);
\draw[blue] plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (1,2) (3,1) (4,3)};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Smooth curve in red green and blue]

`\clip` is used to only show the part that is in the clipping path - here a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

probably like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.15]
  \definecolor{red}{HTML}{F00000}
  \definecolor{blue}{HTML}{0000F0}
  \definecolor{green}{HTML}{008000}

  \coordinate (P1) at (6,6);
  \coordinate (P2) at (22,30);
  \coordinate (P3) at (42,30);
  \coordinate (P4) at (70,24);

  \coordinate (C1) at (11.16,16);
  \coordinate (C2) at (16.31,26);
  \coordinate (C3) at (27.69,34);
  \coordinate (C4) at (33.91,32);
  \coordinate (C5) at (50.09,28);
  \coordinate (C6) at (60.04,26);

   \draw[line width=2, red] (P1) .. controls (C1) and (C2) .. (P2);
   \draw[line width=2, blue] (P2) .. controls (C3) and (C4) .. (P3);
   \draw[line width=2, green] (P3) .. controls (C5) and (C6) .. (P4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: good, I am thinking use the same draw command will keep connection smooth. if split it as 3 command, then how to keep the connection point smooth?

Comment: @lucky1928 If I understand well, you can use the out and in control points of the Bezier curve, with `calc` library to calculate the control points as the midpoints between the key points (for instance ($(P1)!0.5!(C1)$) calculates the point midway between P1 and C1).

Comment: I have updated a update section on my question to show what does the smooth issue mean!